# NodeJS Decryption Routine to C#

Tags: c#, node.js

Can some body please convert the code below to .NET. I've tried by code but it is failing. I tried with c# the code below. and some other attempts as well. With C# I am getting incomplete block error

`````````````
               function reverse(vencryptedText, clientId, subject) {
                if (!vencryptedText) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid encrypted text');
                }

                const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
                hash.update(SALT + clientId + subject);
                let key = hash.digest();
                let iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 1);

                const encryptedText = vencryptedText.substring(VERSION.length);
                const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
                let canonicalIdentifier = decipher.update(encryptedText, 'hex', 'utf8');
                canonicalIdentifier += decipher.final('utf8');

                return canonicalIdentifier;
            }

````````````
c# code

``````
    static string Decrypt(string value, string salt, string clientId, string subject)
        {
            byte[] cipherText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value); ;
            string plaintext = null;
            SHA256 hash256 = SHA256.Create();
            string keyString = (salt + clientId + subject);
            byte[] IV = new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
            byte[] Key = hash256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString));
            using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                            plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        } 
``````
`````````````

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried? You may be very close to it.

Comment: Hi, THis is what i tried with.